# Binomial expansion for $n^{\rm th}$ root

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients

The binomial expansion of the square root of $1+n$ is well known:

$$
(1+n)^{1/2}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{i}n^i=1+\frac{n}{2}-\frac{n^2}{8}+o(n^3).
$$

But what do we know about the expansion of $(1+n)^{1/m}$ for positive integer $m>2$?

Comment: In the RHS., shouldn't it be $\omicron (n^3)$?

Comment: You must use the known binomial development with some careful: So you get $$1+\frac nm-\frac{n^2(m-1)}{2!m^2}+\frac{n^3(2m^2-3m+1)}{3!m^3}+\frac{n^4(-6m^3+11m^2-6m+1)}{4!m^4}+\cdots +O(n^k)$$ where you can calculate till the exponent $k$ you want to get.

Comment: @Piquito what do you mean "with some careful"?

Comment: Because  the formula of coefficients is not so immediat  as when $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @Piquito If you add this answer I can accept it!

Comment: @Piquito If you add this answer I can accept it!

Comment: It is not necessary, dear friend. The important for me is that you get what you want to know.

Comment: Still no answer to my question?